# MongoDB aggregation to count words of strings' matches

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given the following MATCHES (`$match`) of an aggregation:

```
[
    "palabra": "Hello",
    "palabra": "My name is Rafael"
]
```

the next `pipeline` for `aggregate` gives me a total `$sum` of 2:

```
    var pipeline = [
        {
            $match: {
                "_p_evaluatedByUser": "_User$" + userId
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                palabra: 1
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$palabra"
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "result",
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ];
```

I'm actually looking for a `pipeline` able to do `$sum: $palabra.split(" ").length` so it would be returning `5` instead of `2`.

Is there any easy approach from my initial `pipeline`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your $unwind:

```
    {
        $project: {
           "words": {$split: ["$palabra", " "]}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$words"
    },
    {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          allwords: {$push: "$words"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            wordCount: {$size: "$allwords"}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Genius. Thank you very much